# YQL corrupting JSON (different from arrays getting converted to Objects issue!)

Tags: javascript, ajax, cross-domain, yql

This is the cross domain JSON (GeoJSON) I am trying to fetch using Jquery AJAX.

http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/geojson-reprojected.json

Here is my query:

```
url: "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql"
q: "select * from json where url='" + URL + "'",
format : 'json',
jsonCompat: 'new',
crossProduct:'optimized'
```

Before the issue was that YQL was converting arrays with length 1 into an object. But I added jsonCompact: 'new', and that fixed it. But now the JSON returned has a new Issue. 
Some where inside the JSON structure, it converts all Array of Arrays into Array of Objects which contain Arrays :( Yep thats confusing, So I am posting a Snap Shot comparing Orignal with YQL. Does any one know a solutino for this? I tried adding 'crossProduct':'optimized' but there is not change. Here is the comparision snap one on left is orignal, right shows one returned from YQL:

[image: Left: Orignal JSON, Right: One returned from YQL, NOT SAME!!!]

Comment: let me know if you find any solution to this.

Comment: no luck! its broken :(

Comment: i am finally doing "select * from html..." to get raw json string. And then converting it to json with: JSON.parse(...body.p);